# Why is altair single select not changing my graph?

Tags: dropdown, altair

I've tried to google why this isn't working but it doesn't appear obvious to me. Can you please tell me why the selection dropdown isn't changing the graph?
Thanks

```
source = data.unemployment_across_industries.url
df = data.unemployment_across_industries()
series_val = df.series.str.split(',').explode().unique().tolist()
print(series_val)
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=series_val, name='Industry: ')
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['series'], bind=input_dropdown)

fig3 = alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    alt.X('yearmonth(date):T',
        axis=alt.Axis(format='%Y', domain=False, tickSize=0)
    ),
    alt.Y('sum(count):Q', stack='center', axis=None),
    alt.Color('series:N',
        scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category20b')
    )
).add_selection(
    selection
)
fig3
```

Answer (score 1):

The selection doesn't change the graph because you have not conditioned any part of the graph on the selection (none of your encodings depend on the value of the selection, nor is the data filtered based on the selection).

Perhaps you intended to do something like this?

```python
fig3 = alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    alt.X('yearmonth(date):T',
        axis=alt.Axis(format='%Y', domain=False, tickSize=0)
    ),
    alt.Y('sum(count):Q', stack='center', axis=None),
    color=alt.condition(selection,
            alt.Color('series:N', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category20b')),
            alt.value('lightgray'))
).add_selection(
    selection
)
```

For more on how to use selections in Altair charts, see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html